# How to hold context in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm working on some improvements of our code, in terms of both readability and performance.

We use a container component that loads all the required data and pass it to its child components as Inputs. Sounds to be a good practice overall, but I have some issues in our particular case: this container component contains the whole application except for the header. It contains several child components that are subcontainers and also have several child components of their own. It means that we have to pass the whole context through each container component until it finally reaches the "real" components, and it's a huge bunch of Inputs to add in every container parent -- my favorite container has 18 Inputs that it never uses and only send to its children.

I think it's kind of hard to read, and that I could use a service instead that would be accessed by the top component to set the context data, and then by the relevant components to read the data on need. I'm also concerned by the performances using so many Inputs with some quite large objects.

I couldn't find any good practice to determine the best way to hold a context in Angular, especially when it involves a lot of data. I don't know either if there is another way than using services or Inputs.

I have two questions:

- What is the best way to hold context data across an Angular application?
- Could the abusive use of Inputs throughout many components be an issue in terms of performances?

Comment: Concept is good.  I just load what's absolutely needed for the first small set of components.  This allows to the other components to retrieve data only when needed.  It helps speed up start up time and in essence relies on Lazy Loading techniques, all good all asynchronous all observables.

Comment: So basically, you don't see any issues regarding change detection when using a lot of Inputs in a lot of components? There's no OnPush set in the app afaik, and I'm a bit concerned that the amount of data and the change detection might be one of the reasons we have performance issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What is the best way to hold context data across an Angular application?

Using a singleton like you specified.

You can also a state management library such as AkitaJS, NgRx, NgXs ... (up to your preference). They have the advantage of being able to persist data in the local storage.

- Could the abusive use of Inputs throughout many components be an issue in terms of performances ?

Yes. Particularly if you rely on the default change detection.